# What makes the text on a <button> element vertically centered?

Tags: html, css, webkit, centering

It seems there is some magic around the `<button>`element that I don't understand.

Consider this markup:

```
<button class="button">Some Text</button>
<div class="button">Some Text</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.button{
    background: darkgrey;
    height: 40px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: helvetica;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

    /*I'm aware I could use this to center it*/
    /*line-height: 40px;*/
}
```

What makes the text in the button element vertically centered? Webkit seems to predefine a `-webkit-box-align` with a value of `center` for the `<button>` element. If I set that to `initial` the text is no longer aligned to the center. But that doesn't seem to be the full magic, since on the other hand I had no luck centering the text on the div using the `-webkit-box-align` property.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cburgdorf/G5Dgz/

Comment: Have you tried this on multiple browsers? I'm not sure, but it may be an issue with having to reset browser-styles. Also, maybe this will make your playing with buttons to find out the solution easier? http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/ . It isn't perfect, but it's nice and easy to use whenever I like to find new button styles.

Comment: And here's a fiddle with the default webkit css for a `button` added to the `div` http://jsfiddle.net/v89Bh/2/, but that will not give you (us) an answer to your question

Comment: HTML form elements are rendered at least in part by the native operating system, which is why they're historically so difficult to style. The exact styling isn't always explainable in terms of CSS styles.

Comment: @Johan but still the text is not centered even after applying all the webkit default styles to the div.

Comment: @MattCoughlin yes, I wondered if that affects this case as well. On the other hand the button seems to react to `-webkit-box-align` but then I don't understand why the div doesn't react to that...

Comment: @Christoph yes, I know, strange. Interesting question and I really look forward to someone answering the question.

Comment: @BenYep you are right, I should test that on other browsers as well. Haven't done that yet. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Firefox the same behaviour.

Comment: @Christoph: At the very least, I think you can assume that HTML form elements are outside of the exact classification of inline, inline-block, block, and table-cell. Different operating systems or browsers have different rules for the default styling of these elements, and how they respond to attempts at customizing the styling. The answer may have to come from people with knowledge of the internal details of the browsers' rendering engines. And it may be specific to each combination of operating system and rendering engine.

Comment: Is there a practical application behind your question?  Button type elements are centered vertically and horizontally using padding.  The `box-align` property comes from the 2009 Flexbox specification and should only take effect on *flex containers*, which button type elements are not (by default).

Comment: @cimmanon Nope, there is no practical application. This is pure curiosity. You say the box-align property should only take effect on flex containers, which buttons are not by default. But then, why does the text align to the top when I set it to `initial` (notice that it is `center` by default)

Comment: Something to do with padding: http://jsfiddle.net/wF4Dw/1/

Comment: @dfsq setting the padding to 10 centers the text. That's the recommended technique to use to center it (see @bokorben answer). But it's not what the browser does for the `<button>`element. I was just living under the assumption that nowadays the browser uses only css for all element prestyling. But as it turns out it is not.

Comment: @Christoph This is my point that button does not react to usual CSS. So probably there is something else but styles.

Comment: @dfsq I guess so. So my take away from this is that we can't assume the browser achieves all visual effects using pure CSS.

Comment: @Christoph I don't have an answer as to why Chrome is misbehaving because the spec is very clear as to what type of elements `box-align` is allowed to apply to:  *Applies to: box elements* (see: http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/#propdef-box-align).  Viewing the computed styles indicates that the element is inline-block, not box.  For what its worth, fieldset/legend styling cannot be faithfully recreated on any other type of element.

Comment: @cimmanon highly interesting. I guess we need to wait for a webkit developer to answer what happens under the hood.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I know this is a couple of years old, but I'll add my thoughts after some investigation in to issue while writing a reset stylesheet for a project.

*NOTE** This is based on looking through the Firefox source because it was the easiest to obtain and read through. However, based on similar behaviour in other browsers the implementation is probably similar.*

Firstly, the main issue here is that `<button>` elements - atleast in Firefox - are built with an internal element between the `<button>` tag and it's children. In Firefox it's called `moz-button-content` and isn't something that can be reached with CSS and has been set to display block without inheriting the height of the button, you can see this style declaration in the [useragent stylesheet](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/res/forms.css#649-681):

***From "source/layout/style/res/forms.css"***

```
*|*::-moz-button-content {
    display: block;
    /* Please keep the Multicol/Flex/Grid/Align sections below in sync with
       ::-moz-scrolled-content in ua.css and ::-moz-fieldset-content above. */
    /* Multicol container */
    -moz-column-count: inherit;
    -moz-column-width: inherit;
    -moz-column-gap: inherit;
    -moz-column-rule: inherit;
    -moz-column-fill: inherit;
    /* Flex container */
    flex-direction: inherit;
    flex-wrap: inherit;
    /* -webkit-box container (aliased from -webkit versions to -moz versions) */
    -moz-box-orient: inherit;
    -moz-box-direction: inherit;
    -moz-box-pack: inherit;
    -moz-box-align: inherit;
    /* Grid container */
    grid-auto-columns: inherit;
    grid-auto-rows: inherit;
    grid-auto-flow: inherit;
    grid-column-gap: inherit;
    grid-row-gap: inherit;
    grid-template-areas: inherit;
    grid-template-columns: inherit;
    grid-template-rows: inherit;
    /* CSS Align */
    align-content: inherit;
    align-items: inherit;
    justify-content: inherit;
    justify-items: inherit;
}
```

Because you can't affect any of the styles on this element, you are forced to add you styling on the `<button>` tags. This leads into the second issue - **The browser is [hard coded to vertically position](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/forms/nsHTMLButtonControlFrame.cpp#280-296) the content of the button**.

***From "source/layout/forms/nsHTMLButtonControlFrame.cpp"***

```
// Center child in the block-direction in the button
// (technically, inside of the button's focus-padding area)
nscoord extraSpace =
    buttonContentBox.BSize(wm) - contentsDesiredSize.BSize(wm);

childPos.B(wm) = std::max(0, extraSpace / 2);

// Adjust childPos.B() to be in terms of the button's frame-rect:
childPos.B(wm) += clbp.BStart(wm);

nsSize containerSize = (buttonContentBox + clbp.Size(wm)).GetPhysicalSize(wm);

// Place the child
FinishReflowChild(aFirstKid, aPresContext, contentsDesiredSize,
                  &contentsReflowInput, wm, childPos, containerSize,
                  ReflowChildFlags::Default);
```

Given these two issues you can start to see how the button force the content to be centered, consider:

```
   <button> tag

+------------------------+ ^
| button extra space     | |
|                        | |
+------------------------+ |
|| ::moz-button-content || | button height
||   display: block;    || |
+------------------------+ |
|                        | |
| button extra space     | |
+------------------------+ v
```

If you give the `button` a height - like the `48px` from your fiddle, the text will be centered because the `moz-button-content` element is display block and will only have the height of the content (most likely the line-height of the content by default) and when put next to another element you get this behaviour:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: san-serif;
  background: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height:1;
  vertical-align: baseline;
 }

button, a {
  height: 3em;
}

button {
  background: red;
}

a {
  display:inline-block;
  background: green;
 }
```

```html
<button>Button content</button>
<a>Link Content</a>
```

[This bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=913759) and [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984869) in the Firefox issue tracker was about a close as I could find to any actually documented bug. But the threads give the impression that despite this not appearing in any actual spec, the browsers have just implemented it this way "because the other browsers are doing it that way"

---

There is a work-around to the issue if you actually want to change the default behaviour, but it doesn't completely solve the problem and YMMV depending on your implementation.

If you insert a wrapper `<span>` with `display: block` as the only child of the button and put all your content inside it you can use it to skip over the `moz-button-content` element.

You will need to make this `<span>` element have `height: inherit` so it correctly fills the height of the button and then add your normal button styling to the `<span>` instead, you will get basically behaviour you want.

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: san-serif;
      background: none;
      font-size: 1em;
      line-height:1;
      vertical-align: baseline;
     }

    button, a {
      height: 3em;
    }

    button {
      background: red;
    }
    button::-moz-focus-inner {
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
      outline: 0;
    }

    button > span {
      display: block;
      height: inherit;
    }

    a {
      display:inline-block;
      background: green;
    }

    button.styled > span , a.styled{
      padding: 10px;
      background: yellow;
    }
```

```html
    <button><span>Button content</span></button>
    <a><span>Link Content<span></a><br/>
    <button class="styled"><span>Button content</span></button>
    <a class="styled"><span>Link Content<span></a>
```

It's also worth mentioning the [appearance](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-4/#propdef-appearance) CSS4 rule (**Not yet available**):

While this is not a viable option (as of the 5th January) yet. There is a proposal to redefine the `appearance` rule in the CSS4 draft that might actually do the right thing an remove all assumptions made by the browser. I only mention it for completeness because it may become useful in the future.

**UPDATE - 30/08/2016**
You should actually use a `<span>` instead of a `<div>`, as `div`'s aren't valid children for `<button>` elements. I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Now, that is an answer! Thanks for taking the time to write it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use padding.

For example

```
padding: 20px 10px;
```

Comment: yep, that's another solution to center the text. However, I'm more after understanding what webkit does to center the text. Because it seems to have something to do with `-webkit-box-align`

Comment: This is exactly how button type elements are styled to get the vertically centered effect.

Comment: Yes, that's true. It's just not the question :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that the only reason for this behaviour is that Google Chrome or browsers in general will take the default styles from your operating system.

For example, if you compare the button or scrollbar on Google Chrome run in windows 7 and windows 8:

- In windows 7, the button will have a horizontal gradient line in the center of your button
- In windows 8, the scrollbar are able to fade in and fadeout on click

This is just my opinion but hope that it can give you some ideas :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;` as an alternate method.

Comment: Thanks. I'm also aware about this technique. I'm more after figuring out what the browser does to get it centered.

Answer (score 1):

On Mozilla Firefox I got the [-moz-appearance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-appearance) property :

```
-moz-appareance: button;
```

In the HTML5 draft, there is a [Rendering section](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/rendering.html#the-button-element-0), but doesn't details the placement :S

Comment: But even if I set `-webkit-appearance: button; -webkit-box-align: center;` the div doesn't render the same as the button.

Comment: I know there is some UI element that are internally styled such as spinner button and stuff like that. I reckon opening them to user styling is a work in progress. Maybe the behaviour you describe fall in this category.

Comment: Intersting. I was living under the wrong assumption that in 2013 all the styling for the elements is completely done using predefined CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Button elements by default centers child elements vertically. It isn't done in a conventional CSS way, and therefor isn't trivial to override.

The best solution I have found is setting the button to flex column.

```css
button {
  height: 100px; 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column; 
}

span {
  height: 20px; 
  width: 100px; 
  background-color: blue; 
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span></span>
</button>
```

Some answers suggested adding an inner wrapper, and setting it's height to inherit. This might not work for elements that have their height calculated dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

In case you need to get rid of this behavior you can just add `span` as a child of `button`. Works better than trying to trick all the browsers.