# HTML: What css attribute makes content in button "center"?

Tags: html, css, button, attributes, center

It's a weird and not that important question:
if I create a `button` tag in html, then type some text like "click me" or something

```
<button> Click me! </button>
```

then use `css` to give it `width` and `height`, like:

```
.myBtn{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

The words "Click me!" will automatically be right in the center of my button.
I tried `text-align:left;`, the words will move to the left side,
which means I disable its **horizon center**

but I don't know how to make it **not vertical center** ?
put elements vertical center always has some solution to make it(like after/before, flex, margin...etc), but today I wanna make the contents **not** vertical center in button,
I totally have no idea how to do that execpt changing its top and left.

does any body know what attributes should I change to make it **not** vertical center?

btw, I just wanna know what basic attributes the button has to make its contents center, not the solution of put the content in button to the left-top, so please don't tell me use `top`, `left`, `calc` or something calculate stuff about changing contents' position, that will be great.

Comment: This is default behavior of `<button>` in all browsers. You can use `<span>` instead and style like button.

Comment: I know it's the default attributes of `button`, and this question is exactly asking which default attributes the `button` has to make its contents vertical-center. NOT asking the solution about put elements to the left-top

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What makes the text on a <button> element vertically centered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764600/what-makes-the-text-on-a-button-element-vertically-centered)

Comment: wow, I guess so, I gonna check it later

Answer (score 1):

```css
.myBtn{
  width:100px;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom:82px;
  min-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<button class="myBtn"> Click me! </button>
```

You can use min-height and padding-bottom

Comment: I guess I should make my "btw" more detail... use padding to control position is absolutely like using top or left for me, That's not what I wanna know, sor

Answer (score 0):

you can did this by adding a `<span>` tag to your  `<button>` tag .I'm added the snippet below

```css
button{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  }

button > span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

button:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button>
    <span> <!-- Added wrapper -->
        Click Me...!
    </span>
</button>
```

Comment: I guess I should make my "btw" more detail... use padding to control position is absolutely like using top or left for me, That's not what I wanna know, sor

Comment: that's another way about put element to the top, not the way how button tag make its contents vertical center..