# Why does text inside a button vertically aligns to middle by default when setting height?

Tags: css, button, vertical-alignment

Here I'm concerned about the WHY and not "how to vertically align, etc.".

The button and the link have reset styles and look exactly the same with the applied styles, however when adding an explicit height they behave differently.

FWIW the link behaves the same as other elements (e.g. div), the button is the one that has special behaviour.

```css
.btn {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid;
 font-size: inherit;
 font-family: inherit;
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: transparent;
 padding: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 100px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">&lt;button&gt;</button>
<a class="btn" href="">&lt;a href&gt;</a>
```

Comment: Does it really matter ??

Comment: @CuongHoang off course! :) Otherwise why would I ask :-P Seriously, I'd like to understand what's going on behind the hood, also, but not only, to apply the best solution.

Comment: Right click either and select `inspect` then look at the style inheritances. Notice the `user agent stylesheet` properties added or lack thereof in different element types, to the order of inception, therein lays your answer and keep in mind it may differ between browsers.

Comment: @ChrisW. Thanks, this was the first thing I tried, before posting. There's no user agent style on the button (even the weird 'align-items', since its not flex) which gives this result on the link (or whatever other tag).

Comment: It's the difference in element type between browsers, I'll save the repetition and point to an existing [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764600/what-makes-the-text-on-a-button-element-vertically-centered) that should explain more. Cheers

Comment: @ChrisW. Thanks, I was looking for previous answers but somehow missed it. Exactly what I was looking for.