# How do you make anchor tags and button tags have identical styles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React, and I want to render either a button element or a Link (which transpiles to an anchor tag)

```
if (this.props.link) {
  e = (
    <Link
      className={["button link", this.props.className].join(' ')}
      to={this.props.link}
    >
      {this.props.buttonLabel}
    </Link>
  )
} else {
  e = (
    <button
      className={["button", this.props.className].join(' ')}
      type={this.props.type}
    >
      {this.props.buttonLabel}
    </button>
  );
}

return e;
```

I looked up the default button and anchor styles and normalized them. I still have one problem however. The text on the  is centered vertically and horizontally, but the text on the  is centered only horizontally. I went so far as to copy all the computed styles on the button and apply them to that same class shared by the anchor tag. To be safe, I also normalized .link class which I believe is added by React Links.

What's going wrong here? Here is the CSS for reference.

```
.button, .link {
  /* Normalize anchors nad buttons */
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  background-color: var(--primary);
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  text-shadow: none;
  font: unset;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-rendering: auto;
  text-indent: 0;
  text-transform: none;
  align-items: unset;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1rem;
  height: 3rem;
  width: 8rem;
  writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
  word-spacing: 0;
  font-stretch: 100%;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant-caps: normal;
  font-variant-east-asian: normal;
  font-variant-ligatures: normal;
  font-variant-numeric: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-image: none;
}
```

Comment: When you're styling an anchor element, you should include `:link` and `:visited` selectors as well for global support. (e.g. `.button, .link, .link:link, .link:visited { ... }`)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options;

1. Set `display: tabel-cell;` so your `vertical-align: middle;` applies; or
2. Set `line-height: 3rem;` so it matches your button height.

I would also recommend using a utility library for conditionally joining classNames together in React, such as https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames.

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't understand why it does this. All the extra CSS above is just there because I wanted to make absolutely certain the elements had the same styles. 

Also, I'm not sure I see the advantages of using this class library?

Comment: Also, the vertical-align: middle; does something. The buttons aren't level without it, but setting it at least makes the tops of the buttons at an equal y coordinate. I get that it shouldn't because I'm not using table-cell but it does :/

Comment: Apparently the reason has to do with the way browsers render buttons, so when you set the height of a button it's going to behave differently to an anchor tag. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764600/what-makes-the-text-on-a-button-element-vertically-centered. That said, I wouldn't use `height` to increase the size of a button, try using `padding` instead to manage the height/width.